# How to find the future tense of a word using stanford nlp

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to ultimately determine whether the tense of a sentence is the future tense. My strategy is to find the head verb using StanfordCoreNLP. Then to examine the tense of the verb itself and the auxillary verbs to find if the sentence is future tense.

Do you know how I can decide the tense of a specific verb and the auxillary verbs associated with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POS tags partly give you the tense. 
Here is full list of POS tags and their description: 
[image]

As you can see "VBD" is "past tense". All the followings have VBD label somewhere:

[image]

For future tense you can use modal label "MD":

[image]

For case with compound verbs, I'd use shallow-parser with some rules:

[image]

In this case "is going to be" is an indicator for future tense. Here is the complete list of shallow-parse labels: (from: http://cogcomp.org/page/demo_view/ShallowParse)
[image]

Here is a demo if you wanna work more with it: http://nlp.cogcomp.org/

Comment: What about phrases such as "It is going to be a great day".

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. One final question. Where is the list of shallow parser tags. E.g. what does VP stand for and where can I find a comprehensive list?